# Tailwind updates not showing on local server (NextJS, mac-os m1, Safari)

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind for a personal project with NextJS, but the updates of styles get bugged. Like a lot. It's around 50/50 chance that Tailwind will apply the style to the component, or I have to restart the dev server, update tailwind config, reset the localhost url in the browser and do lots of random things until it works again.

I'm not using any plugins for Tailwind, and I don't think any external thing is causing this (since it's a fresh project of mine and I've had similar issues before).

Here's my package.json if that might help:

```json
{
  "name": "badmood111",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.6",
    "@types/node": "18.13.0",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "eslint": "8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
    "next": "13.1.6",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.4",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

Note: I tried googling a fix and all I found was to create a .env file and add "TAILWIND_MODE=watch" and "NODE_ENV=development", but that didn't help.

Comment: All styles does not work or some of them wont work?
Even you can check if dynamic class names does not work.

Comment: All of the styles still apply, just the ones I modify do not. I have to do all kinds of shinenigans in order to update the styles

Comment: It will be better to share code you modified to see what is wrong.

Comment: Please improve your title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution worked for me, but by scrolling the internet I noticed that all of the people experiencing this issue were using Mac computers...

Tried running the local server on Chrome instead of Safari and it works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this issue was of course to turn my ad-blocker extension off on localhost. This fixed every live-reload issue I was having.

If you're having this problem, chances are it's an extension doing it. JS tooling is getting quite good at handling the other issues that might cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in `postcss.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```